# How do you embed two or more external content sources next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I want to embed two pinterest pins next to each other. Pinterest gives you the html code to do this which looks like this:

`<iframe src="https://assets.pinterest.com/ext/embed.html?id=424605071137135326" height="531" width="345" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>`

I can then easily add this to my website. However, I want to add two or sometimes three of these next to each other. Is there a way to easily do this?

Thanks in advance!

I haven't tried anything and have no idea where to start

Answer (score 0):

You could use either a `Flexbox` or a `Grid`.

Here is an example for `Grid`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .pin-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* Adjust the number to display 2 or 3 pins */
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap between pins */
  }

  .pin {
    width: 100%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="pin-container">
  <div class="pin">
    <!-- Pinterest Pin 1 HTML code -->
    <a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/464997042352611810/"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
    <!-- Pinterest Pin 2 HTML code -->
    <a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/214625356997407101/"></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Add more pin divs as needed -->
</div>

<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or the `flexbox` variety:

```html
/* html */
<div class="pin-container">
  <iframe src="https://assets.pinterest.com/ext/embed.html?id=424605071137135326" height="531" width="345" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  <iframe src="https://assets.pinterest.com/ext/embed.html?id=ANOTHER_PIN_ID" height="531" width="345" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

```css
.pin-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.pin-container iframe {
  margin-right: 10px; /* Optional: Add some spacing between the iframes */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the simplest solution for arranging a bunch of items in a single row.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.side-by-side {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5vw;
  margin: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-by-side">
  <iframe src="https://assets.pinterest.com/ext/embed.html?id=424605071137135326" height="531" width="345" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
  <iframe src="https://assets.pinterest.com/ext/embed.html?id=424605071137135326" height="531" width="345" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
</div>
```